# Access a large database table from multiple threads

Tags: mysql, database, multithreading

I need an expert advice for my database. Basically we have 100s of sensors around the world. We collect data from the sensors and store in the database for future use.

Currently I create a separate database table for each customer i.e. When a customer registers to the application, I create a separate table for them and the data from all the sensors from this customer goes to their separate database table.

Now the number of customers are increasing so does the number of tables and this approach is not looking good anymore (may be this approach wasn't right in the first place).

I now want to keep all the data in one table so I copied all the data from the customer's table into a new table. Now the size of the new table is over 5GB with more than 34 million rows (and growing).

If I want to insert new rows into this new table simultaneously, from multiple thread for each sensor, it takes too long. To access the data from the same table takes long time too.

How can I resolve this issue? Is there any other solution ? Should I use some external cloud service to store data ?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I am using indexes. Here is the table schema

[image]

With UNIQUE INDEX `idx_userInsDate` ( `userID`,`instrumentID`,`utcDateTime`)

I have also looked into the database sharding but my main issue is, inserting rows to the same table from multiple threads and reading data from multiple threads is taking some time.

Comment: It's impossible to answer such a broad question, without any information on the schema or indexes involved. In any case - *why* use a single table when you have such clear partitioning criteria like the User ID? What about the *security* implications? A single SQL Injection vulnerability could expose *everyone's* data

Comment: Furthermore, inserting individual rows in the table will be slow. It would be easier to insert incoming rows into a staging table and load that into the big table periodically.

Comment: In any case, you didn't provide enough information to give a concrete answer expect "don't do that". The database schema shouldn't be decided by the number of tables but by specific requirements and careful consideration

Comment: The type of data is same for all the sensors and the number of tables are increasing constantly, that is why I want to store data in one table. But you are right about the vulnerability...

Comment: You should also check the IoT services and courses by Amazon, Azure. Even if you don't use one of their services, you can copy ideas from them. For example, instead of each sensor writing to the database, you can *append* lines to storage files. These can be customer-specific. Once these get large enough, you import them into the database.

Comment: The type of data is no reason to use a single table. Are you going to run queries against all customer data? Then *maybe* a single table is justified.

Comment: in my opinion I don't think a relation database will help, I think you need to look for NoSql solution like Mongodb,Cassandra,etc so you distribute the data on multiple servers, ofcourse if you don't want to build your own cluster then cloud services will help

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the tips. I shall look into IoT services too.

Comment: @niceman why do you think that any of them would work better? Just because they are NoSQL doesn't mean they are faster. Nor will *distribution* help when all requests end up hitting the same machine, possibly because of a bad partition key, or because they have to be replicated. Never mind that "large" for an RDBMS is data in the TB scale these days (ok, not MySQL)

Comment: @niceman you are probably right, relational database is not good for this scenario. I have heard about mongodb but I am not sure how effective this is or how easy is it to implement. :/

Comment: @Ali it's not the database that causes the delay, it's the design. Don't expect a NoSQL to run faster or exhibit *fewer* problems.

Comment: For example, that index is guaranteed to slow things down, because it indexes data by user *first*. This means that the entire index is modified as new rows are added. It's also inefficient, because user IDs have low selectivity. The result is a deep index in constant change. If the date was first, only the end of the index would have to be updated

Comment: Ohk.. thanks for that, What do you suggest then! should I use multiple indexes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136172/discussion-between-ali-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Answer (score 0):

With this limited information here's my advice.

When collecting millions of rows from many different customers unless the data has to be collected together for "easy reporting" a customer specific table or even a customer specific database can definitely be used and that is absolutely fine.

This actually has several benefits including protecting you from exposing one customers information to another customer on accident since all their data is in 1 table.

As your number of customers goes up then you get either a new database for each customer or a new table and that is fine and that is probably something you would want to automate in your software. For instance, if a customer signs up, this table is automatically created.

Both scenarios and designs are common and perfectly fine depending on your situation.   For instance, I once owned a product company and for that company every customer had their own entire database.  So as my customer count went up my number of databases went up. This is no different really than you having a database or table per customer and if you choose that route that's okay.

Whatever you choose you must consider your sql backups, size of your database versus hard drive space available etc.   If the number of tables continues to grow maybe each customer should get their own database but how hard would it then be for you to backup all of these databases and relate them to central db if you needed to do so.  Just consider everything like this including security and your reporting needs, how much data you will need to keep etc.

Here's another article I wrote some time ago on multi-tenant data architecture.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38555345/671343

Check it out and hopefully this helps you.   Your not the only one to struggle with a design decision about this. Just weigh  all your options considering reporting, security, backups and more.

Hope thats helpful

Answer (score 0):

Use **Mongo** or similar DB for your scenerio , that is the exact scenerio which requires Mongo .

**Multiple Record Insertion at once** is very fast and isolated from other records hence faster\

**Reading is Faster** if you have proper Data structure Tree formed for your data.

**Proper structuring** will furhter help to reduce the requirement of creating new table for each customer.